# Renaming/redefining bibliography results in tocbibind to not work

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

So, I'm working on my dissertation and am trying to get the bibliographies to show up in the table of contents at the correct level. I need a bibliography for each section, so I am using chapterbib.  That works fine.

I'm using the **report** class, which has bibliographies as chapters instead of sections. The final bibliography should be a chapter.  They need to be sections in the individual chapters.  I use renewcommand to rename the chapters to Reference and change them to sections.

If I use tocbibind but not renewcommand, the bibliographies show up in the ToC as chapters title 'Bibliography'.  If I use renewcommand, they do not show up.  Clicking the 'add bibliography to toc' option in LyX results in chapters titled 'Bibliography' to be added to the ToC, even when the actual bibliographies are title 'Reference' and are sections.

I made a small example that has the problem.  If anyone wants it and tells me how to upload it here, I'll do so.

I'm using LyX 2.1.4 with child documents and the following preamble in the pared down example.

```
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{url}
\setcitestyle{round}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

And the renaming/redefining command before the bibtex generated bibliographies in the child documents:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{References}}
```

Summary question:  How to rename and redefine the bibliographies and have them show up correctly in the ToC?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `*`? `\section` and `\section*` do not behave the same way when it comes to numbering things and showing up in the headers or tables of contents.

Comment: And we have a winner.  That fixed it.  Not sure if that's worth a answer, but answer the question and I'll mark this as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in using `\section*` rather than `\section` in the redefinition. The fix is simple:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{References}}
```

The reason is that `*`-forms of sectioning commands print the title, but -- barring other redefinitions by the user or the class or a package -- do not include a number and do not make an entry in the table of contents (and usually in the header as well).